Why Was Suffering Necessary?
G-D wished to bestow good, and so created our perception of reality. This can be found in many sources such as here, here, here, here, Eitz Chaim Chapter 1 -- among others.
G-D could have created what we perceive in any way He wished. Therefore all that we perceive was a requirement/intention of our created reality. While what we perceive can take many forms, one form is one of suffering. We perceive that another experiences something that we cannot quite describe other than "pain" or something of the sort. Some may argue the morality of this. It can be argued, for example, that suffering is required to elevate oneself in some way to a higher being. Others may enjoy it on some level. However, if given the option, not influenced by all the suffering experienced until this point, that it would be better (for them or someone else) that suffering should not have been created and is not "good".
The original cause of this suffering is not revealed to most of us. However it is noted that others (e.g. Navi/Prophet) have been revealed the reason behind the need for suffering in some situations.
Regardless of the reason behind our perception of - or our perception of someone else's - suffering, this was an intentional creation by a Creator who wishes to bestow Good.
Now, if all creations would agree suffering should have not been created, and it was created nonetheless, there is of course a purpose for this. Indeed, the closest documented person to G-D - Moshe Rabbeinu - could not perceive why this is so.
However, I am wondering if there is anyone with some insight on my question:
Why was Suffering required as a potential by-product for a limitless Creator to bestow Good?
Note: @Rabbi Kaii did a good job explaining why suffering is necessary, but from the viewpoint of what we perceive. In other words, we perceive suffering and everything else, and have deduced a purpose for the suffering we perceive. But the question is about it's need/purpose from the viewpoint of it's Creator -- which I realize could very well be unanswerable. A limitless "Good" G-D, in my small view, had no absolute need to require Man to suffer to receive His Goodness. Again, just looking for insights on this hard problem of mine.

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. There is enough space in the question to provide context and more details - to ensure you get great answers. Also since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

The midrashic answer is given in Bereshis Rabba 65:9 (regarding Yitzchak) https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.65.9?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi, however there are big books written on the subject beginning with the book of Iyov. Is there anything specific you are seeking? Try making search on "suffering" to see if the question had been asked here in the past. For example here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=suffering

The work Daat Tevunot by Ramchal addresses this question. It is too much to summarize here unfortunately.

@YDJ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/142465/theodical-arguments-from-bereshit-rabbah-695-why-are-they-rarely-if-ever-used Baruch SheKivanti

There are actually many attempts to answer this in tradition. I was learning something related to it last night, which is part of a larger body of thought on this question, so I am happy to attempt an answer bringing it all together, although it's clear that this is one of the deepest and most difficult questions in all of Torah thought; I don't expect to satisfy everyone, but for what it's worth:
Bread of Shame1
There is a concept of נהמא דכסופא, which is that if Hashem were to give us good without us earning it, it would not be a perfect good. This is a fundamental issue. I've heard two reasons about why it is fundamental.
The first is from Ramchal2, which is that the perfect good is Hashem Himself, and therefore in order to receive that good, we must be similar to Him (more on this in the next point), and just as His goodness belongs to Him, ours must belong to us (and for a finite being, that is achieved through effort - the root of suffering).
The second goes into the idea that unearned goodness is arbitrary, and arbitrariness is not what Hashem wants. Indeed, arbitrariness is not Godly at all, it is associated with tohu, Amalek, and a cold cruel world where nothing matters. See this answer which tries to give a fuller explanation. For Chesed (kindness) to be full-blown love, it must be personal, meaningful. Let that sink in.
Giving vs. Receiving
The Baal Hasulam3 exquisitely explains this idea of Hashem's desire to give. In order for there to be someone who can receive His goodness, they have to be fundamentally different to Him in one respect: they have to have a desire to receive. Therefore, He had to create that from nothing (yesh me'ayin). This creates a catch 22 - the desire to receive makes us so fundamentally different to Him, that it gets in the way of our receiving of His goodness (which, as we said, is Him, Himself). Therefore, He gives us an opportunity to transform this desire to receive into a desire to give (specifically, a desire to recieve in order to give), through effort, so that it is ours.
It's our fault
So far, we've discussed why there is suffering, but we haven't quite covered where evil comes from. The Rebbe Rashab4 explains what da'at really is. It has two elements that are relevant; one is that it is the source of (physical) sensation, and two it is the source of depth of intellect. He then explains love as follows: there is a hidden love (chasadim mechasim), and a revealed love (chasadim megulim).
Adam didn't want hidden love, he wanted to feel it and thus ate the fruit that gives him da'at, and that was the problem. Once love becomes a sensation that one feels, that's where it's possible to love the wrong thing, and that's the root of all evil, and therefore the big job of mankind begins in refining the human spirit to ensure that only love of Hashem can exist in our hearts. This is a very difficult process of birur, clarification, because of the other issue with da'at; its intellectual depth. Intellectual depth is what enables mixture of good and evil, because someone with that depth of intellect can mix and marry opposites, and paradoxes. Deep stuff!
The Yetzer Hara is necessary
The Zohar5 literally says that Hashem needs the Yetzer Hara. As the Tzaddikim point out for us, this is because without the Yetzer Hara, the Neshama (Nefesh Elokit) would not want to be on earth, where it is possible to sin. The Yetzer Hara is like a trap for the Neshama, because it forces the Neshama to enjoy the world, and indeed we receive the Yetzer Hara as children and who is more excited about life than them? However, this of course leads to the possibility of evil, which must be fixed. Our fixing of our Yetzer Hara is indeed the effort, and thus the earning, mentioned previously. See this answer for a bit more on this point, and sources there.
Hashem has a Ta'avah
This is the final point that ties everything together. We are taught that Hashem Himself has a desire, and that desire is to have a dwelling in the very lowest world; this world of physicality6. Hence, we are not (just) doing it for ourselves7, we are quite literally doing Him a service in all this. Therefore, this is quite literally, as fundamental as it gets: this is the fulfilment of Hashem's Essential Will8. Through much Torah study, especially Chassidus, one comes to appreciate this point, and see how it fits into the grand picture. I.e. we come to see what Hashem sees (l'havdil; in our own way) in this project, and realise it is a fantastic, perfect project, and all questions fall away. This takes a life time of study!
Therefore, please feel free to ask for clarification of any of the above points, especially after you have learned the sources provided. It's clear that even this relatively "long" answer is inadequate to fully explain these points, so should be treated merely has "subject headers" for the thoughtful to contemplate and further research.

Final Thoughts
There are many reasons why Hashem made the world the way that He did, and they are all rather fundamental (and they are all deeply connected). Nonetheless, we must ultimately take on faith that Hashem knows what He is doing. As the Radzyner Rebbe writes9, indeed Hashem is truly unlimited, and even though these ideas, in our paradigm, are fundamental, we shouldn't fool ourselves into thinking that Hashem is limited by them. He creates the paradigm from nothing. So, we have to take it on faith that Hashem's purposes are perfect, even if they create very difficult questions, like the one you have asked. Hashem knows what He is doing, and it's our job to serve Him exactly as He told us, and we know that the reward will be the best possible - eternal d'vekut with Him, Himself, for all eternity10. The best possible good!

1. Many sources, originating in Talmud Yerushalmi Orlah 1:3; see Zohar I 4a, R. Yosef Karo's Maggid Mesharim 2:8 etc.
2. Derech Hashem 1:3
3. Introduction to the Zohar
4. פדה בשלום נפשי י״ט כסלו, ספר המאמרים עזר"ת
5. I 23a, Bereshit 16
6. See Tanya, Sefer Shel Benonim
7. אור החמה על ספר הזהר
8. בשעה שהקדימו, יום ב' דחג השבועות, ה'תשי"ב
9. שער האמונה ויסוד החסידות
10. Derech Hashem 2:2

A wonderful and encompassing answer, thank you. I have upvoted your answer because it gives the necessity of suffering shape. However, it still means the creation of suffering of Man was intentional and planned. It's mere existence requires us to accept that it was "worth it" for G-D to create our reality knowing the unfathomable suffering and cruelty that would undoubtedly occur. For me, it sounds like we must pay for G-D to bestow His Goodness to us. A limitless "Good" G-D, in my small view, had no absolute need to require Man to suffer to receive His Goodness. Thank you again!

@Joey No problem, not trying to change your mind :) I do think of it like this though. Asking Hashem to give me good without effort, is equated to asking Hashem to make marriage perfectly good without it being personal between the husband and wife. I can only say that full exploration of the sources I bring will make that statement make more sense (as well as back it up, which I will not do here because I am, as I said, not trying to change your mind). Thanks for the upvote, looking forward to learning with you in future. Big welcome to Mi Yodeya

It's possible to argue that there is a silver lining to all suffering, even when it's not immediately obvious, and many commentators have done that.  But it must be emphasized that, unlike other religions, Judaism does not welcome suffering per se, does not view it as positive, regardless of what comes after it.  The Talmud records three variations of this conversation:

Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Abba fell ill. [Rabbi Yoḥanan went] to visit him, and said to him: “Is your suffering dear to you?” Rabbi Ḥiyya said to him: “I welcome neither this suffering nor its reward.”  [Berakhot 5b]

In other words: I don’t want the suffering even if there is a reward that will come after it.  The story continues:

Rabbi Yoḥanan said to him: “Give me your hand.” Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Abba [did so and Rabbi Yoḥanan] restored him to health.

So, before applying faith healing, Rabbi Yoḥanan had to make sure the patient wanted to recover!  If not, faith healing will not work.  He did not assume the desire for recovery was automatic.
